# Relationship between ManagedThreadID and Operating System ThreadID

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading

I'm working on a multi-threaded C# Windows application that makes frequent calls into a native dll.  These are blocking calls which can sometimes last quite a long time.

In certain situations, I'd like to cancel these blocking calls on some worker threads from the main thread   The native API I'm using provides a function for this purpose:

```
HRESULT CancelBlockingCall(DWORD ThreadID)
```

Although the documentation for the CancelBlockingCall() isn't terribly clear, I believe I need to pass the ThreadID for the OS-level thread which is blocking on the call.  Based on the return codes I'm getting from CancelBlockingCall(), I realized that Thread.ManagedThreadID is not what I need.  I found the following on [msdn (see the Note)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx):

> An operating-system ThreadId has no fixed relationship to a managed thread, because an 
>   unmanaged host can control the relationship between managed and unmanaged threads. 
>   Specifically, a sophisticated host can use the CLR Hosting API to schedule many managed 
>   threads against the same operating system thread, or to move a managed thread between 
>   different operating system threads.

Does this mean that there is no way for me to properly call CancelBlockingCall() for a managed thread?  Is it impossible to determine the ThreadId of the OS-level thread in which a managed thread is currently executing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this mean that there is no way for me to properly call CancelBlockingCall() for a managed thread? Is it impossible to determine the ThreadId of the OS-level thread in which a managed thread is currently executing?

As Aidan said, you can use the [GetCurrentThreadID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183) API to get the OS thread ID.

To keep track of it across managed threads, you could wrap your API calls in a class where you store the OS Thread ID, so that you can stop it later :

```
public class APITask
{
    private uint _osThreadId;

    public void Run()
    {
        _osThreadId = GetCurrentThreadID();
        API.RunBlockingMethod();
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        API.CancelBlockingCall(_osThreadId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

As other people mentioned, you could try p/invoking `GetCurrentThreadId` before calling the blocking native function and registering that id somewhere, but this is a timebomb — some day your managed thread will get pre-empted and re-scheduled to a different OS-level thread between the two p/invoke calls. The only reliable way I can suggest is to write a tiny unmanaged proxy dll, which will call first `GetCurrentThreadId` (writing it into an `out IntPtr` someplace where it will be visible to managed code) and then your native blocking function. A callback into managed code instead of `out IntPtr` might work too; CLR can hardly re-schedule threads while there are unmanaged frames on the stack.

**Edit:** apparently you're not the first person to have such problems: there are two handy methods in `System.Threading.Thread` which allow one to defuse the timebomb I mentioned and p/invoke `GetCurrentThreadId()`: [`Thread.BeginThreadAffinity()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.beginthreadaffinity.aspx) and [`Thread.EndThreadAffinity()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.endthreadaffinity.aspx). CLR host will not re-schedule a managed thread to a different native thread between these calls. Your code needs to run at a high trust level to call these methods, though.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  If I could upvote you again, I would.

Answer (score 2):

You could try P/Invoking the [GetCurrentThreadID](http://pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=GetCurrentThreadId&namespace=[All]) API

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Abortable ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163644.aspx)?

From the article;

> Instead, consider a thread pool implementation that handed you back a cookie of sorts for a queued work item. The pool could then also provide a Cancel method that would take one of these cookies and cancel the associated work item, removing it from the queue or aborting the executing work item as appropriate. Implementing a custom thread pool for this task probably isn't the best idea, but there are other alternatives