# Wrapping INLINE functions

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, wrapper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++/CLI Mixed Mode DLL Creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691325/c-cli-mixed-mode-dll-creation)

I'm wrapping a C++ class using c++ cli. The header file looks like this:

**pabcon.h**

```
class PABCon {
private:
        unsigned int maxIndex;      
        long byteSize;  
public:
    __declspec(dllexport) inline unsigned int GetMaxIndex() { return this->maxIndex; };
    __declspec(dllexport) void invertData();
};
```

I'm wrapping non-inline functions this way:

**pabconwrapper.h**

```
public ref class PABConWrapper
{
private:
    PABCon *pabc;

public:
    PABConWrapper();
    ~PABConWrapper();
    void invertData();
};
```

**pabconwrapper.cpp**

```
PABConWrapper::PABConWrapper() : pabc(new PABCon())
{

}

void PABConWrapper::invertData()
{
    pabc->invertData();
}

PABConWrapper::~PABConWrapper()
{
    delete pabc;
}
```

My questions are:

1) What is the best way to wrap the **inline** c++ functions?

2) What should I do with private variables defined in **pabcon.h**? Should I wrap them too somehow?

Thanks

P.S. I've touched C++ last time 4 years ago and coded in C# since then.

Comment: Do you mean inter-operate with them from C#? And you would make another function to access the private variables unless you planned on doing some sniffing around the bytes of the class

Comment: @Jay exactly, I need those inline functions in c#

Comment: Use PInvoke if you just need the calls.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388405/how-to-make-c-p-invoke-code-called-from-c-sharp-thread-safe

Comment: @Jay I can't use PInvoke as the C++ functions are not static.

Comment: Make a function which is static then :) Also what are you trying to 'inline' as you can't inline something which is already inlined...

Comment: @Jay I would make them all static if I could :) But I can't really modify the c++ code. I have only compiled dll and corresponding header files

Comment: Yes, you can... (at run-time, dynamically) but No you don't have to... Create a new C++ code to do it and then call that function and again what are you trying to inline? the function is already inlined.

Comment: @Jay I showed here just a simple example. It's nearly impossible/to much overhead to make them static. I do not try to inline something, there are inline functions in unmanaged code (delivered header files) and I simply need to have them in managed code.

Comment: They are already in-lined from the managed code because the compiler compiled them with in-line... once compiled with inline you can't change that after the fact.. it's not like `const` your question makes no sense.

Comment: @Jay where? please show me this managed code. I don't want to change them. I want to use them from c# so I need to wrap them somehow. pabcon.h is unmanaged

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function or http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/overview-inline-fns.html

Your un-managed code should have inline defined on the functions it wants in-lined. Managed code is always in-lined when possible. 

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx

Comment: @Jay mate, we don't understand each other. There is an inline c++ function in pabcon.h? This is unmanaged code. See it? OK. Now I need to call this function from the c#. That simple. Do you know how? Thank you!

Comment: @HansPassant not even remotely the duplicate. Keyword is inline

Comment: Right, you really need to stop thinking that it is relevant at all.  It is very unclear why you think it is.

Comment: @HansPassant Not sure what you mean, but if you know the answer you could just post it here instead of marking my question as duplicate (which is definitely not). As I written, I didn't touch c++ for 4 years. I got  header files delivered, seen some inline code and asked how to handle it. If the answer is obvious for you - please help, because not everyone here is as clever/experienced as you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inline: Tagging a method inline is an instruction to the compiler to not emit a function call, but to instead take the contents of the method, and put it directly into the calling function. I believe this is only advisory, the compiler can choose to emit a function call anyway. Regardless, you don't need to do anything fancy when calling this function from C++/CLI, so you don't need to do anything fancy when wrapping it. Just wrap it the same as any other method.

private variables: If they're *private* variables, then unmanaged C++ code using `PABCon` wouldn't have access to them. The public interface of `PABCon` is just the public methods, so that's all you need to worry about. (If the C++ class had any *public* variables, then you'd wrap them by creating a property in C++/CLI.)

`~PABConWrapper`: In C++/CLI, `~` is not the destructor, it's the dispose method. As implemented right now, you'll have a memory leak if you forget to dispose your new class. At a minimum, switch the `~` to `!`, and declare the finalizer instead. Ideally, implement both `!` and `~`, delete the unmanaged object in both methods (with a proper null check), and add proper null checks in the other methods. This would be a good & proper implementation of IDisposable.

Comment: special thanks for pointing me to destructors/finalizers