# How to schedule jobs to run on FPU/AVX?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, threadpool, windows-server-2008-r2

.NET thread pool uses threads that map to logical cores.  In turn, on machines with HT, this means scheduling to both HTs for each processor core.

Is there a thread pool of threads that were created with affinity to physical cores instead of HTs?

This is to avoid additional contention in floating-point heavy applications run on CPU. A developer could simply use a custom scheduler and get tasks running, one per FPU/AVX unit.

Comment: If this is really an issue, why not just disable HT in the bios?

Comment: Because workloads change.  Sometimes, it's integer-intensive, and HT brings nearly double the speed.  (Yet another comment could be to use the GPUs.)

Comment: My next question was going to be: how much does it improve your app if you disable HT.  Is 2x theoretical, or have you measured that directly with your code?

Comment: I'm fighting for that last 10% here.  It's not an amazing amount of improvement, but it does help a bit.

Comment: This is when compared to simply scheduling same number of tasks as there are CPU cores on default thread pool

Comment: The thing is, even if you did manage to disable HT for YOUR process, other processes would be still using HT and using those cores you have decided not to.

Comment: The other thing is that if your app is that FP-heavy, don't do it in C#.  You should be using C or C++ and the Intel compiler to get much better performance. https://bitsum.com/tips-and-tweaks/why-you-should-not-disable-hyper-threading-or-why-you-should/

Comment: I'm calling IPP library from my app for signal processing

Comment: And this is exactly the threading behavior I'm looking for.  Everything else runs as it does, but scheduler gets a hint that these signal-processing tasks should run on the next available FPU.  Do not pass go, do not try to schedule to an HT whose twin is executing more signal processing just now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183311/discussion-between-gregc-and-neil).

Comment: So you might be aware of it already but HT might help FPU performance because (assuming INTEL) multiplication has a latency of 5 cycles but a throughput of 1 cycle (different depending on model). What this means is that if you order your instructions correctly you get 1 multiplication per cycle (or even 8 with AVX) but if you do it wrong you just get 1/5 multiplication per cycle.  Processor Out of Order execution tries to help you but can't do miracles. HT can help here.

Comment: With that said if you need custom affinity I would look for a ThreadPool library that supports modifying affinity of the threads in ThreadPool.

Comment: Micro-optimizations are internal to IPP library.  This is a macro scheduling question, please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1281697/90475